# Are Firebase Bolt rules deprecated?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've seen that the new Firebase documentation doesn't include the Bolt rules section.

Anyone know if they are deprecated or unsupported?

Comment: from https://github.com/firebase/bolt/graphs/contributors it seems that not too much happened from Feb 2016

Answer (score 3):

Bolt is a research only project and learning from the language was incorporated into firebase storage security rules (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/). 
There is no official support for bolt.

Comment: Thanks  @Behrang. Do you work for the project or have found that in an authoritative place?

Comment: While Bolt is being at an experimental stage, I'm using it successfully in production since a while now. I wrote a story on how I'm using Bolt in my projects at https://medium.com/@wcandillon/firebase-schema-evolution-ea830a62c14e.

Comment: @wcandillon I wonder if in 2020 you're still using it or is there any other alternative for good Realtime Database model versioning?