# How to document a Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Whats the best way to add documentation around a Firebase Database, its nodes and the security precautions needed?

So far I've used comments in the database-rules.json or a separate markdown file.

Lack of access to the markdown file in the Firebase Console made me favour using comments but they became excessive, and that's not helping with the actual readability of the schema.

Is there any way to emulate something akin to the documentation in Polymer, where the comments are translated into a docs page?

Comment: I don't think this question is a great fit for Stack Overflow and I'm inclined to vote for its closure. However, one tool that I've found useful for managing complex Firebase schemas is [bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt). I don't know how you are using comments in JSON, but bolt supports JavaScript comments. There is a language reference [here](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/docs/language.md).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Improper docs do cause a lot of "stack overflows" type things, IMO. Thanks for the recommendation tho!!

Comment: @cartant I do agree that the question doesn't really fit on Stack Overflow. But I like it so much that I upvoted it anyway. Any idea where this would be more on-topic?

Comment: @Frank, I didn't really want to close it either. It might fit better on [softwareengineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), but it's still the sort of question that could have multiple, valid answers - so maybe not. Looking at the OP's update, it might be better left on SO, but re-framed along the lines of: how can I extract comments like these from [`json5`](http://json5.org/) and generate Markdown? As for a comment-preserving JSON5 parser though ... dunno. That's kinda broad though, so the OP would have to make a start on it.

Comment: @Frank whats your opinion on Bolt? I found this on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37638885/are-firebase-bolt-rules-deprecated

Comment: @cartant by OP, do you mean me? Should I rephrase the question as parsing JSON comments into markdown?

Comment: Yep, you are the [OP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146513/what-does-op-mean). Your question could be useful to others, but, in its current form, it's not a good fit for SO (it's opinion based and too broad). I'd suggest removing the opinion-inviting *"what's-the-best-way"* to focus it on a problem: generating documentation for Firebase rules from comments in the JSON. (And maybe ask if there are alternatives.)

Comment: The [`js-comments`](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/js-comments/) package might go a long way to doing what you want to do. It will parse comments into an AST and you can render output by defining a template. It looks pretty useful. If you are able to solve your problem with it, please post a [self answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Regarding Firebase, it's unofficial/beta/whatever, but there [this](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/issues/147) has been said and [this](https://github.com/firebase/bolt/issues/179), too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @cartant !! Since bolt is still supported I'm going to look into that over hacking a solution. Having a complier for rules seems more normal somehow. Plus unofficial things scare me.